# xamarin forms speech to text does not work

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Hello I am learning xamarin forms,

I want to use speech to text cognitive service using the microsft   [Plugin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/quickstarts/setup-platform?tabs=xaml%2Clinux%2Candroid%2Cbrowser&pivots=programming-language-csharp#next-steps)   but I got these errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project
Error       linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)   MyApp.iOS
Error       Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class: GTMAppAuthFetcherAuthorization. The symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMAppAuthFetcherAuthorization' could not be found in any of the libraries or frameworks linked with your application.    MyApp.iOS
Error       Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class: GTMKeychain. The symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMKeychain' could not be found in any of the libraries or frameworks linked with your application.  MyApp.iOS
Error       Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class: GTMOAuth2KeychainCompatibility. The symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMOAuth2KeychainCompatibility' could not be found in any of the libraries or frameworks linked with your application.    MyApp.iOS
Error       Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class: OIDAuthorizationRequest. The symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_OIDAuthorizationRequest' could not be found in any of the libraries or frameworks linked with your application.  MyApp.iOS
Error       Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class: OIDAuthorizationService. The symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_OIDAuthorizationService' could not be found in any of the libraries or frameworks linked with your application.  MyApp.iOS
Error       Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class: OIDAuthState. The symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_OIDAuthState' could not be found in any of the libraries or frameworks linked with your application.    MyApp.iOS
Error       Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class: OIDIDToken. The symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_OIDIDToken' could not be found in any of the libraries or frameworks linked with your application.    MyApp.iOS
Error       Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class: OIDServiceConfiguration. The symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_OIDServiceConfiguration' could not be found in any of the libraries or frameworks linked with your application.  MyApp.iOS
Error       Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class: OIDURLQueryComponent. The symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_OIDURLQueryComponent' could not be found in any of the libraries or frameworks linked with your application.    MyApp.iOS
Error       Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTMAppAuthFetcherAuthorization. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.    MyApp.iOS
Error       Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _OIDOAuthErrorResponseErrorKey. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.  MyApp.iOS
Error       Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _OIDOAuthTokenErrorDomain. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.   MyApp.iOS
Error       Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _OIDResponseTypeCode. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.    MyApp.iOS
Error       Native linking failed. Please review the build log and the user flags provided to gcc: -ObjC -lsqlite3 -LC:/Users/xxx/.nuget/packages/microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech/1.14.0/build/Xamarin.iOS -lMicrosoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core -force_load C:/Users/xxxx/.nuget/packages/microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech/1.14.0/build/Xamarin.iOS//libMicrosoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.a -ObjC -lc++ -lsqlite3 -lz -ObjC -lz -lsqlite3   MyApp.iOS
```

I have tried to add  [[protocal]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/troubleshooting/mtouch-errors#MT5211)   on top of IOS classes but I still have these errors

Thanks in advance

Comment: We could use the function by using `Xamarin.Essentials` instead of using the SDK. Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/text-to-speech

Comment: It is speech to text not text to speech

Comment: You could using using Azure Speech Service . https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/azure-cognitive-services/speech-recognition

Comment: I am already using it

Comment: So does it work in Android ?

Comment: yeah it is working on Android